# Centering a Div in a Div (As well as sizing a div based on size of content)?

Tags: html, css

Okay, so, I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong. So let me just show you:

This is what I'm trying to accomplish (made in PS):

http://puu.sh/ryXC9/7d82671ee0.png

What my results are so far:

http://puu.sh/ryXST/02c9722a53.png (Obviously not successful, and as a side note, the orange box is just a placeholder, I'll fill out the form later).

The problem I'm having is first: Trying to have the width of "social-content" to be just the width and height of the held contents. Of course "main-social" is just the width of screen and height of contents. If I can accomplish the width thing with "social-content" then I'll be able to center the div with "Margin: 0 auto" but alas, I cannot figure out my dilemma. This is my relavent markup( "Follow us" bar is excluded, as its irrelevant):

```css
.fa-facebook {
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.fa-twitter {
  color: white;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
#main-social {
  height: 8em;
}
#social-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1.4em;
}
#facebook {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
#facebook a {
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em 0.2em 0.4em;
  background-color: #3b5998;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#facebook a:hover {
    color: white;
}
#twitter {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
#twitter a {
  background-color: #10bbe6;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#twitter a:hover {
    color: white;
}
#emailForm {
  float:left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 7em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d7993286b8.js"></script>
<div id="main-social">
  <div id="social-content">
    <div id="facebook">
      <a href="facebook.com" class="fa fa-facebook fa-5x"></a>
    </div>

    <div id="emailForm">

    </div>

    <div id="twitter">
      <a href="twitter.com" class="fa fa-twitter fa-5x" ></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, the problem also is, It needs to be responsive, the entire site is responsive, and since I'm still new to the responsive scene, I may have not taken the best approaches to it. (Tips not needed, but greatly appreciated :) )

Comment: try adding `display: inline-block` to `#social-content`. By the way, is `width: 70%` required? Because that automatically stretches `#social-content`'s width to 70% of the screen's width regardless of whether the contents inside take up that much space.

Comment: @iamjhu Wow. That's so easy. (And no, I removed it, and with your display: inline-block, it now it the exact height and width of content) however.... Now I cant figure out how to center it according to main-social?

Comment: The entire `#social-content` container? If `#main-social` is simply a container, add `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` to it. That should center `#social-content`. Let me know if that works, if it does, I'll submit it as an answer :)

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know "justify-content" existed. And I searched for this answer for hours! You are god tier. Sumbit an answer and I'll check mark ya ;) PS: That means it worked like a charm c:

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked! I submitted the answer. If you can accept that'd be helpful for when others in the future come across a similar situation. :)

Comment: By the way, if you want to see what else `flexbox` can do, I highly recommend this article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ . I come back to it all the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `#social-content`'s width to be that of its content, use `display: inline-block` without a `width` defined.

If `#main-social` is simply a container, you can use `flexbo` to center `#social-content` within it. Add the following to `#main-social`:

```
#main-social {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; // Centers horizontally
    align-items: center;     // If you need to center vertically, as well
}
```